How to show page details like, Page Owner Name, Edited by, Approved by, Approved Date on a site page in Sharepoint Online modern UI?
I'm new to this. I would like the page details to be displayed at the bottom of the site. Additionally, I want to assign each page to a specific user(is this poosible??).
Example:
Owner: John         Edited By : Max             Approved By : John            Date of approval : 24/06/2024
I tried using the page property web part, but it only displays the title. Then, I attempted to create a custom column by creating site columns, but that didn't work either. I'm running out of options.
Looking for a solution. Thank you.

The properties web part can show fields other than the title. In the screenshot, it is showing the custom field "Owner".
At the top of the page, you can select a different person for the by line manually.
The date the page was last published is showing at the top right.
This is what SharePoint can do out of the box. For any other features you would need to create a custom web part, for example with the SPFx development framework.


Thank you for your reply, but I have only title field in page property web part. Please refer to the image in the link.
https://ibb.co/wzGV9s0

Try editing the web part. In the sde  panel,, you can add more fields and select them from the dropdown. The dropdown only shows some field types.

ok, i will try that.

You need to unseal the Site Page content type by running this PowerShell script.
Connect-PNPOnline <SubsiteURL> -Interactive
$contenttype = Get-PNPContentType -List <ListID> -Identity "Site Page"
$contenttype.Sealed =$false
$contenttype.Update($False)
Invoke-PnPQuery

